# jQuery Toggle divs/add remove class

Tags: jquery

I have a pretty basic jquery script which uses an h2 as a "trigger" to toggle the div below it.

Seen here:

```
$(".toggle-container").hide();
$("h2.trigger").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow");
    return false;
});
```

I've tried to create a "toggle all" link but what happens is the divs that are open or closed aren't being recognized, so it will have the opposite effect. Here is that code:

```
    $("p.toggle-all a").click(function(){
    $("h2.trigger").toggleClass("active");
    $(".toggle-container").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Basically when the p.toggle-all a is clicked, I'd like it to recognize if the toggled divs are closed and if so, open them. Or, if they are open to close them.

Hopefully that makes sense. Any help or advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My read of your question is that if *any* of the items is closed, you want the "all" button to open them; and if *all* are open, you want it to close them. If you really just want to invert their states, [hunter has you covered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246508/jquery-toggle-divs-add-remove-class/4246526#4246526). :-)

But if I've read you right, this should do it:

```
$("p.toggle-all a").click(function(){
    var divs;

    divs = $("h2.trigger:not(.active)");
    if (divs.length > 0) {
        // Some or all are closed, open them
        divs.click();
    }
    else {
        // All are open, close them
        $("h2.trigger").click();
    }
});
```

I've used `$(this).click();` above for brevity, but I'm not a fan of triggering event handlers from code. I'd rather have a function (say, `toggleState`) that is called from the `click` handler **and** from the code above. But it's a style choice, and certainly if you've hooked up the handler with jQuery, you know you can call `click` and trigger it.

Comment: P.S. - I apologize if I wasn't clear in my original statement.

Comment: @jnarciso: No worries, glad that helped. If you haven't voted up hunter's answer, I'd suggest doing so -- it was useful, even if not quite what you were looking for. :-)

Answer (score 2):

why not let the event already set up do the dirty work and just `click()` all trigger `h2`'s?

This will Toggle all, meaning if it was open, now it's closed, if closed, now open

```
$("p.toggle-all a").click(function(){
    $("h2.trigger").each(function() { $(this).click(); });
});
```

This will close all

```
$("p.toggle-all a").click(function(){
    $("h2.trigger.active").each(function() { $(this).click(); });
});
```

This will open all

```
$("p.toggle-all a").click(function(){
    $("h2.trigger:not(.active)").each(function() { $(this).click(); });
});
```

Comment: That will just invert their states.

Comment: @TJ - isn't that what the asker wants?

Comment: @TJ, "I'd like it to recognize if the toggled divs are closed and if so, open them. Or, if they are open to close them."

Comment: My read was different, more of an "open all" / "close all" thing, but re-reading I'd say both are valid interpretations, it's not clear.

Answer (score 1):

You should verify if div is opened or not :

```
$("p.toggle-all a").click(function(){        
    $.each($("h2.trigger"), function(){
        if($this).is(".active"))
        {
            $(this).next().show("slow");
            $(this).removeClass("active");
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).next().hide("slow");
            $(this).addClass("active");
        }
   });
});
```

Comment: Why `$.each($("h2.trigger"), ...)` rather tan `$("h2.trigger").each(...)`?

Comment: Isn't that the same ? Not sure though

Answer (score 0):

```
$("p.toggle-all a").click(function(){
  var h2Trigger = $("h2.trigger");

  if ($("h2.trigger.active").length != h2Trigger.length) // if all are not active then disable and make all active, else make all active
  {
      h2Trigger.removeClass("active");
  }
  h2Trigger.toggleClass("active");
  $(".toggle-container").slideToggle("slow");
});
```